# R: robust standard errors into LATEX

Tags: r, latex, stargazer

I am running some fixed effect regressions with robust stadard errors. And I would like to get them into LATEX format with the stargazer package. Does anyone know how this works in a simple efficient way?

My code for the regressions looks like the following:

```
library(plm)
panel_data <- pdata.frame(data, index = c("country","time"))
FE_model <- plm(Y~X+Z, data = panel_data, model = "within",  effect = "twoway")
```

my code for the standard errors is this:

```
library(lmtest)
coeftest(FE_model, vcov.=vcovHC(FE_model, method = c("arellano")))
```

and the code I previously used with the stargazer package looks like this:

```
stargazer(FE_model_1,FE_model_2,FE_model_3, title="FE_model_Results",
      align=TRUE,
      omit.stat=c("LL","ser","f"), no.space = TRUE)
```

so this would only give me the output of the regressions with normal standard errors, but I would like to use the robust ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using some sample data from `plm` library:

```
data("Produc", package = "plm")
```

Fitting an example model from `plm` library documentation:

```
zz <- plm(log(gsp) ~ log(pcap) + log(pc) + log(emp) + unemp,
          data = Produc, index = c("state","year"))
```

Estimating standard errors as you specified it:

```
se <- coeftest(zz, vcov.=vcovHC(zz, method = c("arellano")))
```

Generating the `stargazer` table:

```
stargazer(zz, title="FE_model_Results",
          align=TRUE,
          omit.stat=c("LL","f"), no.space = TRUE,
          se = list(se[,2]))
```